# How to make hover event, execute every time in jquery rather than first time or even clicking content to execute everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was doing a simple jQuery hover event, but what's going on is it is executing only the first time. How can I make it execute every time? My requirement is whenever I move my cursor over the `<p>` element or click the content inside it, it should alert the content as text.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").hover(function () {
                var s = $(this).text();

                alert(s);
            });
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>
```

as ritesh pointed when i did for webgrid it is not always giving first cell text, here is my code

webgrid

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gridContent tr td:first-child").hover(function(){
      var selectedEmpCode = $(this).text();
                getDepartmentTable(selectedEmpCode);
        },function(){
       var selectedEmpCode = $(this).text();
                getDepartmentTable(selectedEmpCode);
    });
});
```

I am not getting `$(this).text()`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
        alert($("p").text());
        },function(){
        $("p").css("background-color", "pink");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried this way already and it was not working that time,let me try it again, may be some hidden syntax issue

Comment: @peter i tried it locally  works for me

Comment: i was doing prototype, but when i implemented for webgrid row select back the first cell text ,it is not working for everytime. I am updating my question also